ffmpeg enables subtitles even when copying a video
I'm trying to work out why the subtitles are enabled after copying a video.
Given the following:
ffmpeg -i "in.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -map_metadata 0 -map 0 out.mkv

Then out.mkv should be the same as in.mkv.
However, when playing in.mkv in mpv or vlc, the subtitles are off by default. When playing out.mkv the  first subtitle track is on by default. All the subtitles are in both videos, only the container has changed.
What has changed between the two videos? What do I need to change in my command to get ffmpeg to copy the subtitles exactly like they are in the source?
Output of mkvinfo for each
in.mkv
+ EBML head
|+ EBML version: 1
|+ EBML read version: 1
|+ Maximum EBML ID length: 4
|+ Maximum EBML size length: 8
|+ Document type: matroska
|+ Document type version: 2
|+ Document type read version: 2
+ Segment: size 830399474
|+ Seek head (subentries will be skipped)
|+ EBML void: size 1021
|+ Segment information
| + Timestamp scale: 1000000
| + Multiplexing application: libmakemkv v1.17.5 (1.3.10/1.5.2) x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
| + Writing application: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
| + Duration: 00:10:29.728000000
| + Title: 
| + Date: 2024-02-23 13:33:12 UTC
| + Segment UID: 0xe7 0xe1 0xba 0x40 0x30 0xad 0xde 0x0a 0x48 0x32 0x8e 0xe7 0xde 0x33 0x23 0xa0
|+ Tracks
| + Track
|  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
|  + Track UID: 1
|  + Track type: video
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Minimum cache: 1
|  + Codec ID: V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
|  + Codec's private data: size 133 (H.264 profile: High @L4.1)
|  + Default duration: 00:00:00.041708333 (23.976 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 1920
|   + Pixel height: 1080
|   + Display width: 1920
|   + Display height: 1080
| + Track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 2
|  + Track type: audio
|  + "Default track" flag: 1
|  + "Lacing" flag: 1
|  + Codec ID: A_AC3
|  + Language: eng
|  + Default duration: 00:00:00.032000000 (31.250 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Name: Stereo
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 2
| + Track
|  + Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 3
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: eng
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 5 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 3)
|  + Track UID: 5
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: dan
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 7 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 4)
|  + Track UID: 7
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: deu
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 9 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 5)
|  + Track UID: 9
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: spa
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 11 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 6)
|  + Track UID: 11
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: fra
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 13 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 7)
|  + Track UID: 13
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: ita
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 15 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 8)
|  + Track UID: 15
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: jpn
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 17 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 9)
|  + Track UID: 17
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: nld
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 19 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 10)
|  + Track UID: 19
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: nor
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 21 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 11)
|  + Track UID: 21
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: fin
| + EBML void: size 35
| + Track
|  + Track number: 23 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 12)
|  + Track UID: 23
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Language: swe
| + EBML void: size 35
|+ EBML void: size 81
|+ EBML void: size 1021
|+ Cluster

out.mkv
+ EBML head
|+ EBML version: 1
|+ EBML read version: 1
|+ Maximum EBML ID length: 4
|+ Maximum EBML size length: 8
|+ Document type: matroska
|+ Document type version: 4
|+ Document type read version: 2
+ Segment: size 830562950
|+ Seek head (subentries will be skipped)
|+ EBML void: size 80
|+ Segment information
| + Timestamp scale: 1000000
| + Title: 
| + Multiplexing application: Lavf60.16.100
| + Writing application: Lavf60.16.100
| + Segment UID: 0xa4 0x64 0x7b 0xe9 0x7c 0xb0 0x1d 0x4e 0xc7 0x23 0x8e 0xba 0xbd 0x68 0x41 0xba
| + Date: 2024-02-23 13:33:12 UTC
| + Duration: 00:10:29.760000000
|+ Tracks
| + Track
|  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
|  + Track UID: 17922371184661226094
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: eng
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
|  + Track type: video
|  + Default duration: 00:00:00.041708333 (23.976 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 1920
|   + Pixel height: 1080
|   + Interlaced: 2
|   + Video color information
|    + Horizontal chroma siting: 1
|    + Vertical chroma siting: 2
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
|  + EBML void: size 2
|  + Codec's private data: size 133 (H.264 profile: High @L4.1)
| + Track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 11797541849502746104
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Name: Stereo
|  + Language: eng
|  + Codec ID: A_AC3
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Default duration: 00:00:00.032000000 (31.250 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Audio track
|   + Channels: 2
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Bit depth: 32
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 9347406142135526423
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: eng
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 4 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 3)
|  + Track UID: 17614533544185427175
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: dan
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 5 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 4)
|  + Track UID: 15080634680247253829
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: deu
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 6 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 5)
|  + Track UID: 3727375321019824028
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: spa
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 7 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 6)
|  + Track UID: 2896199601525833363
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: fra
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 8 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 7)
|  + Track UID: 892918147131596278
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: ita
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 9 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 8)
|  + Track UID: 14205182556155292975
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: jpn
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 10 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 9)
|  + Track UID: 15906129167387009234
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: nld
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 11 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 10)
|  + Track UID: 14830322772922010588
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: nor
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 12 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 11)
|  + Track UID: 8409901381049276601
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: fin
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
| + Track
|  + Track number: 13 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 12)
|  + Track UID: 5915465592480181972
|  + "Lacing" flag: 0
|  + Language: swe
|  + "Default track" flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Maximum block additional ID: 0
|+ Tags
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|  + Simple
|   + Name: ENCODER
|   + String: Lavf60.16.100
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 17922371184661226094
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 9931713
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:29.670708333
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 15097
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 781712753
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001011
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:29.670000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 11797541849502746104
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 192000
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:29.760000000
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 19680
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 15114240
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001100
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:29.760000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 9347406142135526423
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 49832
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 394
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 3856418
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001200
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 17614533544185427175
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 38472
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 362
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2977250
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001201
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 15080634680247253829
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 45654
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 366
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 3533060
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001202
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 3727375321019824028
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 40968
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 366
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 3170409
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001203
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 2896199601525833363
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 39100
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 366
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 3025890
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001204
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 892918147131596278
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 41073
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 366
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 3178531
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001205
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 14205182556155292975
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 29470
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:17.971520833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 372
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2276482
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001206
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:21.684000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 15906129167387009234
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 35803
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 340
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2770741
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001207
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 14830322772922010588
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 34767
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 366
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2690583
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001208
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 8409901381049276601
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 39362
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 364
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 3046132
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 001209
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 5915465592480181972
|  + Simple
|   + Name: BPS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 35966
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00:10:19.097645833
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_FRAMES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 346
|  + Simple
|   + Name: NUMBER_OF_BYTES
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2783377
|  + Simple
|   + Name: SOURCE_ID
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 00120A
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: MakeMKV v1.17.5 linux(x64-release)
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: 2024-02-23 13:33:12
|  + Simple
|   + Name: _STATISTICS_TAGS
|   + Tag language: eng
|   + String: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:10:22.685000000
|+ Cluster

What option am I missing to get ffmpeg to copy the subtitles exactly as they are?
I can set s:disposition but I want to use the values from the original video
